# Rails url helpers not working in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, helper

I am new to programming, this is my first application.
While creating an application in Rails, i have two models. User&list,nested.

```
resources :users do
  resources :lists
end
```

These are the following routes i obtain with this setting:

```
user_lists GET    /users/:user_id/lists(.:format)             lists#index
           POST   /users/:user_id/lists(.:format)             lists#create
new_user_list GET    /users/:user_id/lists/new(.:format)      lists#new
edit_user_list GET    /users/:user_id/lists/:id/edit(.:format)lists#edit
user_list GET    /users/:user_id/lists/:id(.:format)          lists#show
           PUT    /users/:user_id/lists/:id(.:format)         lists#update
           DELETE /users/:user_id/lists/:id(.:format)         lists#destroy
```

With regards i have created the views with the following links.

```
<div class="stats">
  <a href="<%= user_lists_path(current_user) %>">
    <%= pluralize(current_user.lists.count, 'List') %>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <%= link_to 'Create List', new_user_list_path(current_user) %>
</div>
```

These work as expected, however when i use the same url helpers in testing i get an error.

```
describe "List create page" do 
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do  
    user.save
    visit new_user_list_path(user)
  end
  it { should have_selector('title', text: 'SocialTask | List') }
  it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Create list') }

  describe "invalid list creation" do 
    before { click_button 'Create list' } 
    it { should have_content('Error in creating list') }
  end
 end
```

This causes the tests to have an error.

```
Failure/Error: visit new_user_list_path(user)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `lists' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried playing around with the url that did not work. 
I tried updating rspec/capybara that did not work either.
I have also checked the inclusion of

```
config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

in the spec helper.

How do i get the helpers to work? Or am i missing some minor detail?
Thanks in advance.

Helper Methods.

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user 
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user 
end

def current_user 
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil 
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def current_user?(user)
  current_user == user
end
end
```

The rspec helper to sign in.
support/utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper
 def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
 end
```

Comment: Any idea why this is the case? Despite creating a user with FactoryGirl?

Comment: Yes once the user is created, it gets signed_in.

Comment: The user login step is not shown in the RSpec example you posted. You need something like `sign_in(user)`.

Comment: I already have a helper in the support/utilities.rb. Edited my post to show it.

Comment: I spotted the error. In the test file i only added "user.save" and forgot to put in "sign_in user" Once i did that, all the tests passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the stack trace, I think your problem is in the view on this line:

```
<%= pluralize(current_user.lists.count, 'List') %>
```

It seems like `current_user` is nil. Normally you should define some kind of helper method in your RSpec suite to simulate a user logging in. That way, `current_user` will return the user that you stub out in the test.

Here's an example:

```
# spec/support/session_helper.rb
module SessionHelper
  def login(username = 'admin')
    request.session[:user_id] = User.find_by_username(username).id
  end
end
```

Yours will differ depending on how you authenticate your users. For example, Devise publishes its own set of test helpers, so you can simply include its helpers directly:

```
# spec/support/devise.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Comment: As i said the view's work perfectly fine. The application functions exactly the way intended. I have edited my initial post to display the helper methods. My authentication is done with scratch, outlined by the Hartl tutorial.

Comment: These helpers are specifically for the test suite. If the application works correctly and the tests are failing, it indicates that you aren't "logging in" during your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's getting an error because the user doesn't exists. Try to change `user.save` to `user.save!` then you'll catch the error on creation I think..